# Как вывести в консоль все числа которые кратны 5?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Есть функция:

```js
const multiplicityCalculation = (n, maxNum) => {
  let count = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < maxNum; i++) {
    if (i % n === 0) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
};

multiplicityCalculation(5, 1000);
```

Функция возвращает к-сто чисел которые кратные 5. Как можно вывести в консоль по порядку эти числа? Буду благодарен за помощь)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самое простое, но не совсем корректное: написать `console.log(i);` внутри `if`

---

Чуть более сложное, но верное (т.к. не смешивается логика и вывод информации):

1. Внутри функции объявить массив
2. В условии `if` добавлять это число в массив
3. Вернуть из функции объект

   ```
    { 
        count: ТУТ_КОЛИЧЕСТВО_СОВПАДЕНИЙ, 
        numbers: ТУТ_МАССИВ_С_ЧИСЛАМИ 
    }
   ```
4. Получить результат функции из вне
5. Пройтись циклом по объекту.numbers и вывести в `console.log` их

Answer (score -1):

```
const multiplicityCalculation = (n, maxNum) => {
    let number = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < maxNum; i++) {
      if (i % n === 0) {
        number.push(i);
      }
    }
    return number;
  }
  
  console.log(multiplicityCalculation(5, 1000));
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]